# Python - multiplication between a variable that belong to the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

How to set a class variable return to other data type (list or int)?

So I have two variable that is belong to the same class and I want to use the operator for example multiplication to both of the variables, but It cannot be done because both of them have the class data type.

For example:

```
class Multip:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} x {}".format(self.x, self.y)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.x*self.y)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        thisclass = self.x*self.y
        otherclass = other
        return thisclass * otherclass
a = Multip(5,6)
b = Multip(7,5)
c = a*b
print(c)
```

This will return an error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        14 a = Multip(5,6)
>        15 b = Multip(7,5)
>   ---> 16 c = a*b
>        17 print(c)
>
> in **mul**(self, other)
>        10         thisclass = self.x*self.y
>        11         otherclass = other
>   ---> 12         return thisclass * otherclass
>        13 
>        14 a = Multip(5,6)
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Multip'

Comment: Because you have not implemented `Multip.__mul__(self, other)`.

Comment: Also your representation is a bit clunky; you should probably distinguish between Values and Operations. Maybe take a look at SymPy for some ideas?

Comment: @HughBothwell oh sorry, forgot to write it. So I actually have the mul function but because the argument for the other variable is in form of class type so it cannot be done. any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @HughBothwell do you mean my repr? I will try to look at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work, do this:

```
otherclass = other.x*other.y
```

instead of

```
otherclass = other
```

This will mean otherclass is an int and the multiplication will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is called overloading.  You need to either override the `__mul__` method, the `__rmul__` method, or both.  `__rmul__` is how you would deal with multiplication of different types, while `__mul__` works if both are of the same class.

Add methods like this to your class:

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    print '__mul__'
    return result
def __rmul__(self, other):
    print '__rmul__'
    return result
```

I did not add any operations in those, because I'm not sure how you plan to do the multiplication, but there are overloading methods for all mathematical operators.